# Android, Xamarin: Unable to start program "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: android, visual-studio

this is so annoying. 
Yesterday, everything worked fine. I commited my work on my app and went to bed.
Today- nothing works.
I try to debug my program, the app installs on my phone and works but the debugging stops only with: Unable to start program "The system cannot find the file specified".
No matter how ofter I rebuild, set my project as start project, change the target api, or what not. I even updated everything on my computer but it is hopeless.

Please, help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/124494/suddenly-cant-debug-and-up-against-a-deadline) looks like a promising solution for this issue but somehow it didnt work for me, so I tried to repair my Visual Studio 17 and it worked.

For repairing visual studio you have to download visual studio installer from [official microsoft website](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)

If VS is already installed in your machine you'll get a screen with options :- Update, Launch and more.

select more and click repair.

You have to wait until VS finishes repairing. Hope you'll get rid of this annoying issue.

Comment: hi there. i fixed it myself then by simply reinstalling everything. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and solved it like this:

*As Luminous_Dev figured out here:
forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123640/xamlctask-error-on-new-cross-plat-solution
make sure Mono Debugging for Visual Studio is enabled.*

Tools > Extensions and Updates> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123611/unable-to-start-debugging-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Answer (score 0):

make sure **Mono Debugging** for Visual Studio is enabled.

T**ools > Extensions and Updates> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio**